# "Destination unreachable (Network unreachable)" from physical router to virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, routing, port-forwarding, webserver

For a bit of context, a relative of mine wanted to host an application on his port 30000 so he could play with his friends online on a server located on his machine. However, as he can't setup port forwarding due to not having control over his router, he asked me to find a solution.

I came up with the following setup: I would install Wireguard on a virtual machine hosted by my laptop with bridged connection, connected to my local network. I would then configure my router to port-forward the port 30000 to said virtual machine, which would then be connected through the setup VPN to his computer, on which the server is hosted. The VM would then route the packets towards this server.

The setup isn't fully functionnal yet, but I can connect to his server through my local network by connecting to my VM. I can't, however, use my network's public IP address to access said server from the Internet.

Here is the exact setup:

- My laptop (`192.168.1.168`) hosts my virtual machine (`192.168.1.124`). It is able to connect to the required server through a web-browser by accessing `192.168.1.124:30000`, and so can every machine on my local network.
- My relative's laptop (`192.168.110.2` (Through Wireguard)) is connected to my virtual machine (`192.168.110.121` (Through Wireguard)). He can ping my VM but I have noticed that I cannot ping his machine; But since CURL requests and other connections work just fine I've ignored it.
- My router (`192.168.1.1`) was configured to port-forward port 30000 and my wireguard port to `192.168.1.124`.

After investigating a bit, I couldn't find anything wrong in my setup which is why I turn to you... The most promising lead I have is that Wireshark, when asked to track communications beetween `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.124`, only sees one message when I reboot my physical router ressembling:

> 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.124: (ICMP) Destination unreachable (Network unreachable)

Does anyone have any idea about what is going on please? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Your relative's VM setup is either NAT or Host Only (based on the IP above). Is the Network set up as Host Only?

Comment: @John his setup doesn't involve any VM, 192.168.110.2 is the address of the Wireguard interface on which he is connected. The other interface on my VM is set to Bridged, so it connects directly to my local network from my understanding of things.

Comment: @Chachoune963 - 192.168.110.2 wouldn't exist outside of his network.  If the VPN is hosted on YOUR network, then connecting to 192.168.110.2, would stay within his own network and would never reach any device outside of their network. I am making an educated assumption this is a remote configuration type deal, otherwise, you really should specify all devices are in the same network.